# how I can restore my deleted c# form design

Tags: c#

I have already done a project with C #(WinForm),I loosed my code completly and only I have my exe file  I can recover all the deleted code by dotpeek . how can I recover my form design?

Comment: The form design is usually recovered alongside the already decompiled source. What project are we talking about? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: My project was Win Form

Comment: I guess you might want to have a look at [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/11/reverse-compiling-windows-forms.html).